# How to hide "Open in analytics studio" button when the Einstein Analytics Dashboard is displayed

Tags: lightning-apps, einstein-analytics, einstein, einstein-analytics-dashboards

I am using Einstein Salesforce. I need to use Einstein Analytics Dashboard and add it to a page in Lightning App Builder. However, I need to hide "Open in analytics studio" button when the Dashboard is displayed. See image/explanation below:

[image]

Based on my investigation I think there is no way to hide the button in a native way while dragging and dropping in the lightning page builder. If someone knows better please advise. If you think that I need some css/js/aura based hack to access the DOM after rendering of the dashboard please suggest an approach. It should work (meaning "Open in analytics studio" button should be hidden) even when the user refreshes the page, changes filters in Dashboard, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the ***"Show Header"*** from the properties on the right side.
This will remove the entire header row including "Open in Analytics studio" Button

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the "Show Header" option works sufficiently -- only if you don't have a need to provide the ability for users to use the "Share" button (which allows them to download a png image of the embedded dashboard).

Within the Tableau CRM Dashboard Component, the Header Bar also appears if either Show Sharing Icon or Show Title is selected. (Please upvote ["Don't show dashboard header bar if Show Sharing Icon or Show Title is selected](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000wnZsQAI)" idea via ideaexchange. https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000wnZsQAI)

Many thanks,
Jocelyn